# Find count of unique value of each column and save in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data like this:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

Need to count unique value of each column and report it like below:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | 3 | 3 |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 5 |
| C | 1 | 3 |
| C | 7 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
```

I have no issue when number of column are limit and manually name them, when input file is big it become hard,need to have simple way to have output

here is the code I have

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_csv('1.csv')

A=df['A']
B=df['B']
C=df['C']

df1=A.value_counts()
df2=B.value_counts()
df3=C.value_counts()

all = {'A': df1,'B': df2,'C': df3}
result = pd.concat(all)
result.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over column and insert them in dictionary.
you can initiate dictionary by `all={}`. To be scalable you can read column by `colm=df.columns`. This would give you all column in your df.

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_csv('1.csv')
all={}
colm=df.columns
for i in colm:
    all.update({i:df[i].value_counts()})

result = pd.concat(all)
result.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and then convert `Series` to `DataFrame` by [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and :

```
df=pd.read_csv('1.csv')

result = (df.stack()
            .groupby(level=1)
            .value_counts()
            .rename_axis(['X','Y'])
            .reset_index(name='Z'))

print (result)
   X  Y  Z
0  A  3  3
1  A  1  1
2  A  2  1
3  B  2  5
4  C  1  3
5  C  7  2

   X  Y  Z
2  A  3  3
0  A  1  1
1  A  2  1
3  B  2  5
4  C  1  3
5  C  7  2

result.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

to find unique values of a data-frame.

`df.A.unique()`

to know the count of the unique values.

```
len(df.A.unique())
```

unique create an array to find the count use len() function